# How to be notified of a change that is made on an alternative in another session in GE Smallworld?

Tags: smallworld-gis

I have two Smallworld sessions (Core 4.x) both are on same alternative, the first one has made the alternative writable and the other one is obviously in readonly mode.

I want my readonly session to be notified and refresh the map each time the writable session commits a change.

If I am using a short transaction, I need to start and end a dummy short transaction on readonly session, and if there I am in a long transaction mode I need to `switch(:write)`or `rollforward()` so it updates the database and map respectively on my readonly session. But in both cases the readonly session is not being notified of changes and it has to check for changes regularly through a light weight background thread. I have already tried `observer` and added one to `gis_ds_view`, yet it does not work when changes that are made in another session.

Is there any way that I could be aware of changes in another session?